# Re-arrange elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, textfield, focusout

I am trying to do a small code exercise that my friend made for me. The point of the app is to type the asset name in the text field and using javascript the text in the box will move up to the center, and when you type in another asset name, the old one will go down and the new one will move up. Below is the HTML, CSS & JavaScript code, any help will be great :)

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='faux-address-bar']").focusout(function() {})
})

$("assest1").focusin(function(){
$(span).css("vertical-align", "top");
});
  
$("assest2").focusin(function(){
$(span).css("vertical-align", "top");
});
  
$("assest3").focusin(function(){
$(span).css("vertical-align", "top");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  &:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="?asset=1" name="faux-address-bar">

<div class="container">
  <div id="asset1"><span>ASSET 1</span></div>
  <div id="asset2"><span>ASSET 2</span></div>
  <div id="asset3"><span>ASSET 3</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since this is a coding exercise, I'm curious what else you've done so far (other than bind an event handler for `focusout`)?

Comment: well here is what I thought would make it work but it did not.   
    $("assest1").focusin(function(){
    $(span).css("vertical-align", "top");
     });
  
    $("assest2").focusin(function(){
    $(span).css("vertical-align", "top");
    });
  
    $("assest3").focusin(function(){
    $(span).css("vertical-align", "top");
    });

Comment: Put the code in the question, it's hard to read in comments.

Comment: You have a number of typos in there. `assest1` should be `asset1`. You also need to put `#` before an ID in a selector.

Comment: Focus usually is on input fields, not DIVs.

Comment: Why not ask your friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some free time and wanted to try your friend's exercise as well.

My solution assumes:

1. The input box `?asset=n`, where `n` is the number to change, will always follow the pattern `?asset=n`.
2. ES6 is `a-o-k`.
3. CSS is `not` cheating.
4. Ignoring anything other than the latest version of Chrome...is perfectly fine.

With that said, I wanted to leverage ordering provided by CSS (I'm old school and contrary to what others may say/that I recently read on-line, I believe Separation-of-Concerns in the wild-wild-west that we call `front end development` *isn't* dead).

With that said, shake-and-bake(tm) in some CSS variables, and re-arranging becomes **much** easier!

My algo sucks (I didn't spend too much time thinking about this), but it's one approach that hopefully others may learn from (or be introduced to something new...) If you think of a way to optimize the code, I'd love to see it!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hmcv0tn/1/

```js
// Look ma, no globals!
{
    // Cache queried elements for quicker reference
    let input = document.querySelector('[name="faux-address-bar"]');
    let container = document.querySelector('.container');
    let children = container.querySelectorAll('div');

    // Define our onkeyup handler
    let handler = e => {

        // Because we assume ?asset=n is constant, we can
        // reference the number after = as our element to
        // re-arrange
        let val = e.target.value;
        let assetIndex = val.split('=')[1];

        // Check for presence of element to re-arrange
        if (assetIndex && container.querySelector('#asset' + assetIndex)) {

            // CSS3 variable keys to modify
            let keys = ['--first-item', '--second-item', '--third-item'];

            // Our forEach callback for re-arranging elements
            let swapper = (order, idx) => {
                let el = children[idx];
                el.style.setProperty(keys[idx], order);
            }

            // Default ordering of elements using CSS3
            // flexbox ordering
            let set = [1,2,3];

            // Updates ordering based on asset entered
            switch (assetIndex) {
                case '1':
                    set = [2, 1, 3];
                    break;
                case '3':
                    set = [1, 3, 2];
                    break;
                default:
                break;
            }

            // Blindly loop over set and apply order to elements
            set.forEach(swapper);
        }
    }

    // Registers our key up handler
    input.addEventListener('keyup', handler, true);

    // For fun, update the order on load
    handler({target: input});
}
```

```css
:root {
  --first-item: 1;
  --second-item: 2;
  --third-item: 3;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #aec8f2;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #5b7193;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: all 1s;
  font-size: 30px;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 5px solid #d8efc2;
  background-color: #82996c;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  order: var(--first-item);
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
  order: var(--second-item);
}
.container div:nth-child(3) {
  order: var(--third-item);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="?asset=1" name="faux-address-bar">

<div class="container">
  <div id="asset1"><span>1</span></div>
  <div id="asset2"><span>2</span></div>
  <div id="asset3"><span>3</span></div>
</div>
```